# Python task execution issue

Tags: python

so I am trying to write a python code with some web sraping and excel stuff (checking weekly realestate prices) and I have some functions around 6 that I need to execute, mainly for loops. My problem is that the first function scrapes the site and adds the found items to my excel sheet, the next one checks the prices, and the next one does some editing on the excel sheet. The issue is that when the editing is done, it looks like the code is still "looking at" the version of the excel that is not modified, so basically what I need is to say to the code to wait until one function is over and then you can move to the next.

```
def main():
delete_empty_rows('A')
scraping_base(column_data('F'))
weeks()
cities()
price_and_age()
status()
wb.save('prices.xlsx')
```

Comment: Python will do that by default. You must be doing something concurrently in one of those functions. We'd need to see the contents of the function that gets started but not finished in order to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question all that well, and I'm a little skeptical on how you're performing your for-loops, but a way to space out time between your functions discretely is by using Python's `time` package. e.g.

```
import time
time.sleep(10) # waits for 10 seconds before executing misc_func()
misc_func()
```

Drawback to this would be that your code would run slower...

Answer (score 0):

To put the program on wait for some for example 2 minutes you need to insert this line of code

```
import time
time.sleep(120)
name_of_example_func()
```